# Programmatically create a keyboard shortcut in Revit

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

Can I programmatically create a keyboard Shortcut to my add-in's in Revit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manualy, you can by adding a line to KeyboardShortcuts.txt located in the Revit Program folder. Look at these posts for more explanations: http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/addin-keyboard-shortcut.html and http://blog.rodhowarth.com/2009/04/how-to-create-keyboard-shortcuts-to.html

But as this file is stored in Program Files, you will not be able to write to it without being logged as administrator (Windows Vista, Windows 7). And Revit can lock it also.

Comment: Just a little update, in Revit 2012, it's a XML file - http://blogs.rand.com/architectural/2011/07/revit-2012-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Building Coder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/03/revit-2013-and-its-api.html) you should be able to do this through the API as of Revit 2013.